# Find out, which mode is in use

Tags: major-mode, lisp

Suppose I want to code something like this

```
case mode in
   lisp-mode)
       do-something
       ;;
   shell-mode)
       do-other
       ;;
   latex-mode)
       do-different
       ;;
esac
```

What would be the best way to do this in lisp? Especially, how to find out, which mode is in use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See `major-mode` variable to find out major mode:

> Symbol for current buffer’s major mode.

See `cond` function to do something depending on mode:

> Try each clause until one succeeds.
>
> Each clause looks like (CONDITION BODY...).  CONDITION is evaluated
>   and, if the value is non-nil, this clause succeeds:
>   then the expressions in BODY are evaluated and the last one’s
>   value is the value of the cond-form.
>   If a clause has one element, as in (CONDITION), then the cond-form
>   returns CONDITION’s value, if that is non-nil.
>   If no clause succeeds, cond returns nil.

E.g.

```lisp
(cond
 ((eq major-mode 'lisp-interaction-mode) (message "lisp interaction mode"))
 ((eq major-mode 'text-mode) (message "text mode")))
```

Also see `derived-mode-p` function:

> (derived-mode-p &rest MODES)
>
> Non-nil if the current major mode is derived from one of MODES.

Comment: This could also use `pcase` to remove the repeated `eq major-mode`; e.g., `(pcase major-mode ('lisp-interaction-mode (message...`